# Is concept of virtual memory about memory isolation or about ability to swap? Or both?

Tags: memory-management

Most reading I found about virtual memory, such as http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=89 or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory always state that virtual memory is a concept that allows operating system to make it "appear as though you have more memory than you really do".

But isn't that what overcommit is about? Isn't whole virtual memory concept primarily about the fact that each process has an isolated virtual memory pool, thus being unable to read or modify other process memory?

If not, what is this technology of memory isolation within own virtual memory pools called?

Answer (score 4):

I would say virtual memory is not only about making memory appear bigger than it is, but also about providing many other memory related abstractions, like dealing with pages that are currently not in main memory, adding properties to memory (i.e. non-executability), and standardizing the memory layout of each process. It also allows easy relative addressing in large continuous blocks of data, which might not be able to be allocated contiguously if there was no memory virtualization.

Overcommit in my opinion is less about making it appear as if you had more memory, but more about not actually allocating physical memory if there is no need to do so, like when you allocate a huge chunk of memory "just for safety" which you have no intention of actually using.

Also, you might be confused about what sets apart overcommit and virtual memory, as they are not really two different things, but overcommit is just a part of how Linux and other operating systems implement their virtual memory.

About your last question, I would say that this is just an instantiation of process isolation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_isolation), using the technology of virtual address space.

Answer (score 0):

“Virtual memory” on its own is about virtualising memory, that is providing something that behaves as if it was memory, but isn’t.

The hardware that is typically used to support virtual memory can often be used for other purposes, like protecting different processes from each other, mapping files into memory, lazy loading of program code as required, or sharing library code between multiple processes while using memory for it only once.